# Compute the Lebesgue measure

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Compute the Lebesgue measure of the following set $$S =\left\{(x, y, z) ∈ \mathbb{R^3}: x ≥ 1, \hspace{1mm} y^2 + z^2 ≤\frac{1}{x^2}\right\}$$
So here, $x∈[1,\infty)$ and $y^2+z^2∈(0,1]$. To compute the Lebesgue measure, should I generate all the sets from these two or am I completely wrong? It's just that I can't figure out any other solution for it.

Comment: Integrate and use calculus

Comment: @AndrewZhang Integrate what, which function

Comment: Integrate the function $f(x,y,z) = 1$ over $S$; that should do it.

Comment: You should have learned somewhere that the Riemann and Lebesgue integral coincide whenever both are defined. As Robert said, $\int_A d\mu = \mu(A)$ by definition, where $\mu$ is any measure.

Answer (score 1):

Since we have $z^2\ge 0$, we need $\frac{1}{x^2}-y^2\ge 0$, so $-1/x\le y\le 1/x$. For any point $(x,y)$ we can take any $-\sqrt{1/x^2-y^2}\le z\le\sqrt{1/x^2-y^2}$. The volume for $S_+=\{(x,y,z)\in S:z\ge 0\}$ is then exactly $\int_1^{\infty}\int_{-1/x}^{1/x}\sqrt{1/x^2-y^2}\mathrm dy\mathrm dx$, so the volume of $S$ is $V=2\int_1^{\infty}\int_{-1/x}^{1/x}\sqrt{1/x^2-y^2}\mathrm dy\mathrm dx$, yielding
$$V=2\int_1^\infty\frac{1}{x}\int_{-1/x}^{1/x}\sqrt{1-(xy)^2}\mathrm dy\mathrm dx=2\int_1^\infty\frac{\pi}{2 x^2}\mathrm dx=\pi.$$

**Alternative**: You may also notice that for given $x$ the set $D_x=\{(y,z):y^2+z^2\le 1/x^2\}$ is a disc with radius $1/x$, so the area of $D_x$ is $\pi/x^2$. Hence, the volume of $S$ is $\int_1^\infty\pi/x^2\mathrm dx=\pi$. Hence, we could also use polar (cylindrical) coordinates to compute the volume.

Comment: You did a typo at the volume of the $S_+$ in the upper limit of the second integral and also at the volume of S, it should be $\frac{1}{x}$ not $1-x$. Other than this everything looks good, thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I corrected the typos and added an alternative, for fun, that exploits the rotational symmetry of $S$.

Comment: One more question, we need the volume of S because we have 3 coordinates, right?

Comment: If you mean the volume as opposed to the area, then yes. The set $S\subseteq\mathbb R^3$ is three-dimensional, i.e.~it has a volume, hence the Lebesgue measure of $S$ is posiive.

Comment: Out of curiousity, is it possible to sketch the set, or not?

Comment: Sure, it's possible. Take the graph of $f(x)=1/x$ for $x\ge 1$ and rotate it around the $x$-axis. The resulting solid cone is the set $S$.

Comment: To plot the cone as a function, you would plot $f(x,y)=1/(x^*+y^2)$ on the set $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2:x^2+y^2\le 1\}$. I would also do it, but I don't know how to in WolframAlpha.

Comment: Any reason why are we taking $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ for $x \geq 1$?

Comment: Yes, because $y^2+z^2\le r^2$ gives you a disc of radius $r$ in the $y$-$z$-plane, so in this case the radius for given $x$ is $\frac{1}{x}$. The function $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ for $x\ge 1$ is the radius, depending on $x$. The rotation gives you the discs for given $x$, and the volume in total.